# EXCEL - Calculating Multiple Billable Units by Total Cost

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking at a formula that can calculate the quantities of two different billable units by the final costs.

We are charge .11p for 10 or more units, and .22p for fewer than 10. We only receive the final cost of both together, but it would be extremely helpful to know exactly how many of each are charged. (They are not able to share this information)

I can reach the answer using Goal Seek, but would like a formula that would work.

i.e. We are charged £302.46 for a total of 2726 units.

How could I work this out using formulas?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what's the result you're seeking using what exactly information?
e.g. You would like to get the quantity of total units, knowing only their total cost was X. By the way - if what I wrote is actually what you're trying to get - can you explain how you got the number of 2726 units out of cost of £302.46?

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy to do, but as `shemadolev` points out, the values given cannot be correct (unless one can purchase non-integer quantities which, if so, is very much not obvious and so needs stated). Not a deal breaker to giving a solution, but if this is a real problem, not homework of some kind, you have a typo, or your vendor cannot bill accurately (the latter of which should be hunted down and stomped out... 4p this time, maybe a lot more some other time).

As to this problem itself, if there were a single kind of billable unit and you wanted to break down how they were "purchased" (how many purchased 10 or more at a time vs. how many purchased in lower quantities), it would be easy from the material given nd I will show you that in a moment. BUT you say there are two kinds of these units and you actually want to know how many of each kind of unit, not the batches they were bought in. DIFFERENT thing and the data given is utterly silent on how to distinguish them and without being able to, there is no answer at all to your question. So, to at least show you how to differentiate on how they were purchased:

To understand the solution, consider the cost of all the billable units if billed as taken 1 at a time. 2,726 bought one at a time for 22p each would be £599.72. Every one of them bought in a batch of 10 or more would be some amount less than that, 11p in this case (22p - 11p = 11p). So each bought that way would reduce the billing from the £599.72. Find how much that amount was reduced and you can divide by that difference to find how many units were bought at each rate.

This is Excel, so I won't bother showing this algebraicly, I'll just set it up for Excel. Say you put the total billed in `B1` and the number bought in cell `B2` (labels for the cells in column A) and then put the cost per unit purchased in batches of <10 in `B4` with the cost of batches of >=10 at a time in `B5`. Then the following formula would tell you how many were bought in batches of <10:

```
=(B2*B4-B1)/(B4-B5)
```

(It multiplies the number of units by the <10 cost to find the maximum they could have cost, then subtracts how much they really cost. It divides that result by the difference in the two costs (higher cost minus lower cost). Done. That's how many were bought in batches of <10. Subtract that from the total bought (`B2`) and you have how many were bought in batches of >=10.)

The result is not a pair of integers (2,702.4 bought in batches of <10 and 23.6 bought in batches >=10). Hence why we both say there is a defect. Perhaps they can be purchased in non-integer quantities? So 23.6 bought in batches (one or two batches, but not more than two for this quantity) of >=10 could make sense. But... **if they are only purchasable in complete hour quantities** (so 19 or 6 or 1, but never 12.3 or 7.5 units at a time), **the data is flawed**. That's the minor repair needed, with giving a `meaningful` way to distinguish between the two kinds of units being the hugely major edit required.

Once you provide both edits I just mentioned, someone can modify the above to suit. But the way to distinguish them must be useful:  It has to distinguish in a way that can be used, not in some way that has no bearing on how to tell them apart from just pricing data.

It is very hard to picture just what that might be. Even if you could say one kind is always purchased in batches of >=10, it still would not guarantee that the 23.6 from above were that kind as they could as easily be the other kind as well so... not distinguishing anything.

So... if you can provide a useful way to distinguish them, then yes, the above approach can be adapted and answer your needs from fairly minimal information, just like your math homework in school showed again and again. If you cannot, the answer is "No, one cannot tell you the breakdown from this minimal information."